# How to dynamically set the DefaultLanguage in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, environment-variables, conditional-statements, rewriting

Is it possible to set the `DefaultLanguage` in .htaccess according to an environmental variable or a rewrite condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shell env variable in `DefaultLanguage` like this:

```
DefaultLanguage ${_LANG}
```

Where `_LANG` is the env variable set before Apache process has been started. I start my Apache as:

```
sudo bash -c 'export _LANG=de && /Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh'
```

Comment: No I tried many things like `mod_rewrite` and `mod_setenvif` but `DefaultLanguage` doesn't like anything other than this.

Comment: what about using Using 'FilesMatch'? http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html#FilesMatch_Directive

Comment: That should work I think if you this seeing only for certain files.

Comment: Thanks, I have just suggested some working alternatives. what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion of some alternatives based on `en.example.com/aout`

**Using the command-line interface**

Starting apache with

```
sudo bash -c 'export _LANG=en-US && /Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh'
```

and in .htaccess

```
DefaultLanguage ${_LANG}
```

from previous answer by anubhava

**Using FilesMatch in .htaccess**

```
<FilesMatch "^en\.">
DefaultLanguage en-US
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^en-US\.">
DefaultLanguage en-US
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^es\.">
DefaultLanguage es
</FilesMatch>
```

from: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html#FilesMatch_Directive

**Using mod_rewrite in .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#get language from host name
RewriteRule ^ - [E=LANG:en]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(es|fr|en|se)\. [OR]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=LANG:%1]

Header always set Content-Language "%{LANG}e"
```

Comment: Is `Content-Language` same as `DefaultLanguage`?

Comment: good question. This is just a set of suggestions. I am asking the same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726955/htaccess-is-content-language-same-as-defaultlanguage