# .htaccess - Is Content-Language same as DefaultLanguage?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In .htaccess what is the difference between doing

```
Header set Content-Language en
```

and

```
DefaultLanguage en
```

Comment: I think the difference is in telling other Apache modules the language, for "content negotiation", as [noted under `AddLanguage`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addlanguage)

Comment: +1 A very good pertinent question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DefaultLanguage` is intended for set the default language when a directory contains multiple language files, e.g.: `index.html.en`, `index.html.fr`.
They need to be set with AddLanguage in Apache configuration somewhere:

```
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage fr .fr
```

Files will these extensions will be delivered with the `Content-Language` HTTP header. If no extension is provided, can be a coincidence to have both methods generating the `Content-Language` header but if you want to explicitly set the document Content-Language may run slightly faster with explicit header definition, as it does not need to check the file extension and fallback to a default language if set.

Comment: and what about DefaultLanguage en-US ??

Comment: Use lowercase, as suggested in the [Apache mod_mime documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addlanguage).

Comment: ok thanks! and lastly is it possible to implement AddLanguage with the following url structure: en-us.example.com/about  ??

Comment: Not tested, but try combining it with [`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/) to hide the .html.en extension.